# How to create input field with two entries, but on the opposite side

Tags: html, css

Can someone tell me how to create input field with two entries, but on the opposite sides? Entries should be fixed and predefined.

So basically i need an input field with the place holder "Name" on the left side, and placeholder "Michael" on the other(right) side of the input field.
So when the user starts typing in the text field, text will start form the right but the placeholder "Name" should be fixed and always stay on the screen.

Example:

```
[Name:------------------Michael]
[Last name:--------------Dawson]
[City:-----------------New York]
```

So 'Michael', 'Dawson' and 'New York' are user provided information(user type them).

So before user starts to type form looks like this:

```
[Name:-------------------------]
[Last name:--------------------]
[City:-------------------------]
```

And when user starts to type his input starts from the right.

```
[Name:-----------------------Mi]
[Name:---------------------Mich]
[Name:------------------Michael]
```

Can this be done with pure html/css?

Comment: Can't you just make 2 input fields but remove their borders and stick them together?

As for the predefined use placeholder="Your text"

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Consider adding a sketch or other visual representation of your goal. Or maybe explain your use case more. What are "opposite sides"?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot add a picture because I don't have enough rating. This fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/w254dyo4/) shows what I would like to accomplish, but this particular solution with two input fields does not suit my project.

Comment: @Alek, updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/w254dyo4/). Option Two should be perfect.

Answer (score 3):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/w254dyo4/).
This is not hard to do with css:

```
.one{
    border:1px solid black;
    border-right:none;
    width:120px;
    padding-left:4px;
}

.two{
    border:1px solid black;
    border-left:none;
    width:300px;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:4px;
}
input:focus{
    border:1px solid black;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 0px white;
    outline:none;
}
.one:focus{
    border-right:none;
}
.two:focus{
    border-left:none;
   width:300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="one" placeholder="Name"><input type="text" class="two" placeholder="Michael">
```

The `width:300px;` is to make the word "michael" look like it is by the end of one single text box.

Comment: you may want to remove the outline on the active input

Comment: yes, but `input:active` or `input:focus` should take care of that.

Comment: Tnx, but is this the only solution? This is not something that would be practical to me considering my project. It would be nice not having two separate input fields.

Comment: updated fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/w254dyo4/) Using only one textbox. &nbsp; for space...

Comment: Option two should be perfect.

Comment: @yak613 But there is another problem.. when I said "Entries should be fixed" I meant that input field is not editable by user. What I didn't say is that Michael field is changeable.. And if the user name is longer than 'Michael' (like 'Alexander')it wouldn't show correctly on the input field.

Comment: Well I need something that is responsive. I created really nice form and don't wont to ruin that by stitching two input fields. So the solution with just one input field would be perfect.